# cPanel - How to change FTP home directory in Centos 6

Tags: cpanel, ftp, amazon-ec2

I have created one Linux centOS 6 instance in Amazon EC2 and installed cPanel on it and started running my websites there. The issue I face is when I try to FTP to the instance with following config

> IP : Instance IP
>   Username : centos
>   Password : Blank
>   Mode : SFTP
>   SFTP Key : Private KEY (PEM) Provided by Amazon EC2 dashboard

I got to view only the `/home/centos` directory. But I want to view the main directory which is back to the `/home` directory. When I tried to click `..` in FileZilla it says:

> Permission Denied

So, i tried the following

```
vipw /etc/passwd
```

and changed

```
centos:x:1000:1000:Cloud User:/home/centos:/bin/bash
```

to

```
centos:x:1000:1000:Cloud User:/ :/bin/bash
```

and even to

```
centos:x:1000:1000:Cloud User: :/bin/bash
```

However, after this change FTP stopped logging in.

So I reverted back to:

```
centos:x:1000:1000:Cloud User:/home/centos:/bin/bash
```

Kindly guide me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

cPanel tends to mess around a lot with the default centos folder structure and permissions etc. 
It looks like you are connecting with SFTP "Mode : SFTP".

If you are looking to connect over FTP as your question suggests you could create a new FTP account via cPanel, setting its root folder to the location of the site you are creating it for, say .../htdocs/public_html/mysite/"